# loading remote data to select2 input type is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

i am trying to loading remote data to select2 input type hidden using following method in asp.net

```
public String ConvertDatasettoArrayList()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        // List<UserDetails> details = new List<UserDetails>();
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=PBSUSER5;database=graph;user id=sa;password=panacya");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_selecttables_info", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(ds);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("[");
        int i = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
        int j = 1;
        foreach (DataRow dtrow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            sb.Append("{id:" + Convert.ToInt32(dtrow["id"].ToString()) + ",text:");

            sb.Append("'" + dtrow[1].ToString()+"'");
            sb.Append("}");
            if (i != j)
                sb.Append(",");
            j++;
            list.Add(dtrow);
        }
        sb.Append("]");

        System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

            string s = sb.ToString();

            return serializer.Serialize(s);

    }
```

This method is returning following string

```
   [{id:1,text:'panacya'},{id:2,text:'items'},{id:3,text:'systems'},{id:4,text:'devlopment'},{id:5,text:'cellphones'},{id:6,text:'textfeels'}]
```

script is , when i bind that string array statically it is working but when binded remote data variable it is not loading.

```
        $(function () {
        alert('calling');

        var d =JSON.parse( '<%=ConvertDatasettoArrayList()%>');
        alert(d)

        $("#ex2").select2({
            data: [{ id: 1, text: 'panacya' }, { id: 2, text: 'items' }, { id: 3, text: 'systems' }, { id: 4, text: 'devlopment' }, { id: 5, text: 'cellphones' }, { id: 6, text: 'textfeels' }]// working fine but for below statement

            data: d// remote data variable it is not binding
        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the JSON-String already contains `'` you would either have to escape them or to use `"` when putting the data into a String. Use the following code to set `d`:

```
var d=JSON.parse("<%=ConvertDatasettoArrayList()%>");
```